Is LCAO only valid for equilibrium state?
If I understand correctly, LCAO states that the molecular orbitals in Born-Oppenheimer can be written as a linear combination of Atomic Orbitals for single nuclei. The coefficients in the sum can be calculated through a minimization algorithm, such as Hartree-Fock.
In examples I see online, this typically involves a molecule in equilibrium state.
However, consider a H2+ molecule which is in the process of forming. As the two atoms move closer together, can their shared MO still be written as a LCAO? Is this approximate or exact? Do the coefficients change as separation distance changes?
What happens when the atomic orbitals are not aligned? E.g. one atom is at a 40 degree angle to the other. How would the MO be computed then?

Atomic orbitals are a complete basis set. Any state can be written as a combination of them.

I don't know if this is the answer you're looking for, but, to a good approximation, doesn't the adiabatic and Born–Oppenheimer approximations suggest that there is no point at which the orbitals are out of equilibrium? My understanding is that the shapes of the orbitals change instantaneously with respect to nuclear motion, which means the LCAO approximation is valid at all times, but will need to be recalculated every time the internuclear distance is adjusted.

@isolatedmatrix What I mean by equilibrium is that the nuclei are at the minimal energy positions, or the standard bond lengths
